# How to prevent images from being too large at lower resolutions?

Tags: css, styling

Hello. I am having troubles with the format of how the three elements are presented! The `html {font-size: 62.5%}` in the styling is decreasing the font size of the entire page.

When I disable `html {font-size: 62.5%}` the three element are getting wider! Almost widescreen!  It is getting too big! I wonder why the `font-size: 62.5%;` having such lot of effect how the 3 blocks are formatted! font-size: 62.5 is a font setting?

There is not text inside for the moment, but it still has effect on it. Why is the line so important for the presentation of the 3 blocks.  Hope it is clear for everybody and someone could help me with this.

[link](https://toffewebsite.nl/example.html)

Comment: You use `rem` units for width and height properties. So if you change the default font-size, your html will be affected -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#ems_and_rems

Comment: Hi. Mr T. thanks for your reaction and input so see what the problem is. very thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Fonts based on the `html` and/or `body` element are relational and like any other CSS properties and values applied to those selectors are inherited. There is a whole thing about relative font sizes and the CSS `em` unit. Arno's answer covers it pretty decently.

This is mostly to get you moving forward with *less code*. You can make the images scale with resolution. I'm at 2560x1440 so I had to downsize the browser window to see the issue. You should remove the `width` property and instead use `max-width: 33%;` (for specifically three images) which scales nicely without even needing CSS media queries for mobile.

Go easy on those `div` elements! I also highly recommend familiarizing yourself with what stable aspects of CSS are available, it's a great time to be a newbie compared to 15 years ago! I added CSS Flex (Grid isn't as mature *yet*) and it's extremely powerful once you get around it's quirks.

```
div.card
{
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-evenly;
}

div.card img
{
 display: block;
 height: 18rem;
 max-width: 33%;
 object-fit: cover;
}

<div class="card">
<img alt="Snowy Mountains" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1519681393784-d120267933ba?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80" />
<img alt="Desert" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1485160497022-3e09382fb310?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2250&q=80" />
<img alt="Canyons" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1506318164473-2dfd3ede3623?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3300&q=80" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi John. very thanks for your input. Now I understand much more about it. This helps me a lot.

Comment: I'm glad to help. Arno was also spot-on though I recommend tackling one aspect of code at a time and *always make a back up of working code* which you'll eventually have a nice collection of stand-alone files that have working examples should you forget. Good luck!

Comment: Hi John. I changed everything in this unit. Here the link: https://toffewebsite.nl/test

Comment: However the third element is on lower screen aligned to the left. I can not figure out to avoid that. Do you now how to solve this. very thanks. p.s the link above this threat is not working anymore. the link of the css is here: https://toffewebsite.nl/test/3blocksfancy.css

Comment: Different question should be posted as a new question though I'll give you some guidance. CSS 1 layouts were about using `float: left|right;` with `display: block;`. CSS2 *enhanced* this with `position` (an `absolute` in another `absolute`, `relative` and `fixed` have their own tricks). On my web platform I now use CSS3's `display: flex` though it's a convoluted way to simplify layout (and `position` is still used sparingly). I recommend experimenting with this: https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/.

Comment: he john. thanks. i will dive further in it. I see that learning css costs a lot of time. but i am sure i will learne it.

Comment: While Mozilla has been taken over by herp-derps the MDN documentation is usually better (not perfect) than most other sites: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS

Answer (score 1):

The font-size: 62.5% is a critical part of how this layout work, this is because it's `rem` based. `rem` units are based on font-size on the root of the document to inherit it's value. Setting the font-size to 62.5% means `1rem` is equal to `10px`.

More about rem uses and styling here: https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-and-using-rem-units-in-css/.

There are two ways you can solve this.

### Changing all your font sizes to rem units. (my pick)

You can change the font-sizes from 16px to 1.6rem. etc.

### Change rem unit to em and set parent font-size

You can also remove the `font-size: 62.5%` from the `html` selector to `#global-3blocksfancy` and change the `rem` to `em` this means the parent element (global-3blocksfancy) font-size will determine the size of the other elements.

Comment: `rem` has been a CSS nook I've been intending to improve my understanding of for years. +1.

Comment: Hello Arno. Thanks for your answer. That i did not see that!. Combined with the answer from john earlier now I understand more about em rem etc.   i changed already and works. i chaanged everything from rem to em.